# How to auto insert into table row html based on cell value in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

**i would like to know if i can insert data into next table row after inserting data into previous cell.**

```html
<form class="ml-4 mb-4 mt-2 needs-validation" action="/tabledata" method="POST">
 <table id='tbl'>
  
      <thead>
        <tr  class="Headerrow">
           <th class="col-2">Account Number</th>
           <th class="col-2">Acount Name</th>
           <th class="col-2">Description</th>
           <th class="col-2">Debit</th>
           <th class="col-2">Credit</th>
           <th class="col-2">Amount(USD)</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        
         <tr name="" class =" DataRow ankita trbar ">
            
              <td><input class="input  " name="Account" id="" list="accountnumber" type="text" /></td>
              <td><input class="input" name="AcountName"  id=""  type="text" /></td>
              <td><input class="input" name="Description"  id=""  type="text" /></td>
              <td><input class="input" name="Debit"  id=""  type="text" /></td>
              <td><input class="input" name="Credit"  id=""  type="text" /></td>
              <td><input class="input" name="Amount"  id=""  type="text" /></td>
              <datalist id="accountnumber">
               <option>101001</option>
               <option>101002</option>
               <option>101003</option>
               <option>168001</option>
             </datalist>
         </tr>
         
     </tbody>
 </table>
 <input type="submit" id="btnFirstGenerateJson" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary m-2 ">
</form>
```

lets say i inserted the first td "Account Number"which is based on datalist,i want  the next td "Account Name" to check value and add data dynamically based on that selection, and if it can be down backwards, i insert Account Name and the account inserted automatically.

any reference will be helpfull
Thanks

Comment: Thanks fo the detailed answer, it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a function to retrieve your data and draw a new row with the values. In the example the function `retrieveAccountData` should be replace with the logic needed.

```js
function insertTableRow()
{
  var new_row = document.createElement("tr");
  var account_number = $('.DataRow [name="Account"]').val()
  var data = retrieveAccountData(account_number);
  
  data.forEach(function(item) {
    var new_col = document.createElement("td");
    $(new_col).html(item);
    $(new_row).append(new_col);
  });
  
  $('#tbl tbody').append(new_row);
  
  return false;
}

function retrieveAccountData(account_number)
{
  // Insert your logic in this function
  // to return an array
  // example:
  if(account_number == "101001") {
    return [
      "101001",
      "Whatever Name",
      "Whatever Desc",
      10,
      20,
      5
    ];
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="ml-4 mb-4 mt-2 needs-validation" action="/tabledata" method="POST">
 <table id='tbl'>
  
      <thead>
        <tr  class="Headerrow">
           <th class="col-2">Account Number</th>
           <th class="col-2">Acount Name</th>
           <th class="col-2">Description</th>
           <th class="col-2">Debit</th>
           <th class="col-2">Credit</th>
           <th class="col-2">Amount(USD)</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        
         <tr name="" class =" DataRow ankita trbar ">
            
              <td><input class="input  " name="Account" id="" list="accountnumber" type="text" /></td>
              <td><input class="input" name="AcountName"  id=""  type="text" /></td>
              <td><input class="input" name="Description"  id=""  type="text" /></td>
              <td><input class="input" name="Debit"  id=""  type="text" /></td>
              <td><input class="input" name="Credit"  id=""  type="text" /></td>
              <td><input class="input" name="Amount"  id=""  type="text" /></td>
              <datalist id="accountnumber">
               <option>101001</option>
               <option>101002</option>
               <option>101003</option>
               <option>168001</option>
             </datalist>
         </tr>
         
     </tbody>
 </table>
 <input type="submit" id="btnFirstGenerateJson" onclick="insertTableRow(); return false;" class="btn btn-primary m-2 ">
</form>
```

Comment: Perfect, thats what i needed

Answer (score 0):

```
<td><input class="input  " name="Account" id="" list="accountnumber" type="text" (input)="document.getElementByName("AccountName").value=document.getElementByName("Account").value"/></td>
<td><input class="input" name="AcountName"  id=""  type="text" (input)="document.getElementByName("Account").value=document.getElementByName("AccountName").value"/></td>
```

Hope that answers your question